# Print value of map referenced by pointer

Tags: go, yaml, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am using Helm to render a file. My values to yaml is

```
team:
  name: abcxyz
```

I would like to assign the value of `team.name` to another variable in the `values.yaml` file. Something like

```
environmentVariables:
  - TEAM
  - .Values.team.name
```

So from my research, looks like the above is not possible. But what I do try to use is something like Go pointer. So what Ive tried doing is something like this:

```
team: &team
  name: abcxyz
environmentVariables:
  - TEAM
  - <<: *team
```

When I render this, I get the output

```
        </default>
        <int>1</int>
        <string>TEAM</string>
        <string>map[name:abcxyz]</string>
      </tree-map>
```

How can I access the value of name through the pointer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is really a YAML question... it seems like you want the alias on the name, not the team collection:

```
team:
  name: &teamName abcxyz
environmentVariables:
  - TEAM
  - *teamName
```